# Curl works but Jsoup gives 405 error for Spotify API

Tags: java, curl, jsoup, httpurlconnection

I am able to curl this url to get the access token for Spotify Web API using the below call from command line:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64 client_id:client_secret>" -d grant_type=client_credentials https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

And I get a response with the api_token. But when I try to do this in java through Jsoup, I get a 405 error:

```
Map<String, String> data = Maps.newHashMap();
data.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");

String clientCred =
    new String(
        Base64.encodeBase64((CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).getBytes()));

String url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URIUtil.encodeQuery(url))
    .header("Accept-Language", "en")
    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + clientCred)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
    .data(data)
    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
    .header("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9"
            + ",*/*;q=0.8")
    .get();
```

Am I doing something wrong in setting the request parameters? I tried a simple HttpURLConnection too, with the same request parameters, and that also fails with the same 405 error.

Comment: Try adding referrer and user agent.

Comment: I tried that too, didn't work. I also tried removing and adding the headers I have shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `-d` flag in `curl` you are actually sending a `POST`. If you make a `POST` with `Jsoup` It will work.

But `Jsoup` will complain with a `org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException` because server will respond with `Content-Type: application/json`. Then you have to add an `.ignoreContentType(true)` and you are done.

The code would be:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .header("Accept-Language", "en")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + clientCred)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
        .data(data)
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9"+ ",*/*;q=0.8")
        .post();
```

Bytheway, I'm getting a `{"error":"invalid_client"}` because I don't have a key, but I think you'll be fine.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Yup, making it a post call works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I'm new to Jsoup and don't know when to make POST calls, vs GET vs when to use Jsoup.connect().execute() to get a Response.

Comment: Well, using POST or GET isn't a Jsoup matter, it depends on what the server expects. Generally speaking, if you want to send a form (which is the case) you'll want to make a post. On the other side, using Jsoup's execute allows you to make both http methods (get and post) but also gives you a `Response` object which gives you more information in addition to the response content (status code and response headers, for example). Please refer to the JSoup docs for more information [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html)